# How to disable Tabs header and navigate through button in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using tab-content to navigate to different tabs. I can also navigate through button also, but I want to disable navigation through header.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#info-tab" data-toggle="tab">Information<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#receipent-tab" data-toggle="tab">Recipient <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="info-tab">
<div class="row text-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1">Next</button>
<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="receipent-tab">
</div>
</div>
```

I've go through some links, which tells to remove data-toggle="tab", but if I remove it, I could not navigate through button also.

Here is fiddler link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ngvheehb/

Comment: You want to stop navigation when your click on "Information" and "Recipient" titles...Right???

Comment: yes. Exactly, but it should be navigate through button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#info-tab" data-toggle="tab">Information<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#receipent-tab" data-toggle="tab">Recipient <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="info-tab">
<div class="row text-center">
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" data-toggle="tab" href="#receipent-tab">Next</a>
<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="receipent-tab">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" data-toggle="tab" href="#info-tab">Previous</a>
</div>
</div>
```

#### JQUERY

```
 $("#btn1").click(function () {
 $('li').removeClass('active');
 $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');


});

 $("#btn2").click(function () {
     $('li').removeClass('active');
     $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        });

$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

#### JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/ravipateldhg/ngvheehb/1/